# Java String comparison / matching using boolean query (e.g. contains("('word1' AND 'word2') OR 'word3'") )

Tags: java

I don't really know how to exactly ask that questing but I hope the title says it already.

I am searching for a way (a framework / lib) which provides an ability to do a String.contains() function which tells me if a given String matches a search query.

```
String1: "word1 word2 word3"
String2: "word3 word4 word5"
```

I want to ask:

```
String1.contains("('word1' AND 'word2') OR 'word3'")") ==> TRUE
String2.contains("('word1' AND 'word2') OR 'word3')") ==> TRUE
String2.contains("('word1' AND 'word2')")") ==> FALSE
```

Is there something out which does what I want?
Things like Lucene search framework come to my mind but this seems overkill to what I want to achieve.

Thanks for any hints. If this question is already answered then sorry, I haven't found it.

Thanks
Christoph

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an existing 3rd party library that does this (or something similar)? Another option is to write your own little parser using a parser-generator like ANTLR or JavaCC.

Comment: Yes, I am actually looking for something existing, as I thought, I am probably not the first one having this requirement.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a 3rd party library that does exactly what you want (and not a lot more). If you find something that does what you want it to, it'll probably do a hell of a lot more than just `AND`, `OR` and group boolean expression using `(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene has indeed a [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) type of query that allows you to do just that. But if you really want to do something as simple as your examples, why don't use plain old boolean operators?

```
if ((string1.contains("word1") && string1.contains("word2")) 
   || string1.contains("word3") {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I suppose the question strings are user-entered, not fixed literal strings.

Comment: Yes, it is like Paulo says: The query is user entered and there is only a simple text input field to form the query. I would like the query to be as much "natural language" as possible. Basically like a google search.

Answer (score 1):

The hamcrest matcher library could be useful, it lets you construct such constraints/predicates with any objects (not only strings). The newest version of Junit (4.x) uses this library to allow users to construct such predicate expressions.

http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/

http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial